# Python's print statement followed by sleep(...) function gives unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my Python 3 code:

```
from time import sleep
s='what is your name'
for x in s:
    print(x,end='')
    sleep(1)
```

What I expect is that, each letter will be printed one by one after a delay of one second. But when I run this program, it takes a time of `len(s)` seconds and then prints the value of `s`.
Can anyone explain to me what is actually happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `flush` argument to `print` function:

```
print(x, end='', flush=True)
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print):

> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the
>   flush keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.